# Unknown Provider Error- AngularJS - DreamFactory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app in AngularJS and Ionic, using DreamFactory for my backend. I'm trying to create a controller and a service to obtain data from DreamFactory. The error I'm seeing is:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ScheduleServiceProvider <- ScheduleService <- ScheduleCtrl

Here's my controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('rota').controller('ScheduleCtrl', ['ScheduleService', 
    'DreamFactory', function(ScheduleService, DreamFactory) {

            // Params for call
            scope.callParams = {
                table_name: 'Schedule',
                params: {
                    limit: 20
                }
            }

            // Function to call custom service
            $scope.getRecords = function() {
                ScheduleService.getSchedule(callParams).then(
                    function(result){console.log(result.data.record)},
                    function(reject){console.log("request failed")}
                );
            }
        }
    ])
 })();
```

And here's my service:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    angular.module('rota').factory('ScheduleService', ['DreamFactory',     
        function(DreamFactory) {
            return {
                getSchedule: function(tableNameStr) {
                    // Create request obj
                    var request = {
                       table_name: tableNameStr
                    };

                return DreamFactory.api.sql.getRecords(request);  
            }
        };
    }])
});
```

Comment: seems like the enclosing function is not executed. missed the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this answer to close this question.

Seems like the enclosing function is not executed. Parentheses are missing at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Check your index.html file, i think you have not added your ScheduleService file.

Comment: It is added in the index.html